# Enemies shoot all the time

Tags: c#, xna

I want that an enemy shoots a bullet if the variable nextShot is bigger than the variable shotFrequency. Each enemy should fire independently.
But for the moment, every enemy is shooting all the time. Their are no breaks between the shots. But I want that their always is a little break between the shots. I'm sure that something is wrong about the Enemy class, but I don't know what to change. Could somebody help me, please?

```
public class Map
{
    Texture2D myEnemy, myBullet;
    Player Player;
    List<Enemy> enemieslist = new List<Enemy>();
    List<Bullet> bulletslist = new List<Bullet>();

    float fNextEnemy = 0.0f;
    float fEnemyFreq = 2.0f;

    Vector2 Startposition = new Vector2(200, 200);
    Vector2 CurrentEnemyPosition;

    GraphicsDeviceManager graphicsDevice;

    public Map(GraphicsDeviceManager device) 
    { 
        graphicsDevice = device; 
    } 

    public void Load(ContentManager content)
    {
        myEnemy = content.Load<Texture2D>("enemy");
        myBullet = content.Load<Texture2D>("bullet"); 
        Player = new Player(graphicsDevice);
        Player.Load(content);
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Player.Update(gameTime);
        float delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        for(int i = enemieslist.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {
            // Update Enemy
            Enemy enemy = enemieslist[i];
            enemy.Update(gameTime, this.graphicsDevice, Player.playershape.Position, delta);
            CurrentEnemyPosition = enemy.Bulletstartposition;
            // Does the enemy shot?
            if (enemy.Shot == true)
            // New bullet
              {
                  Vector2 bulletDirection = Vector2.Normalize(Player.playershape.Position - CurrentEnemyPosition) * 200f;
                  bulletslist.Add(new Bullet(CurrentEnemyPosition, bulletDirection, Player.playershape.Position));
              }
        }

        this.fNextEnemy += delta;
        //New enemy
        if (this.fNextEnemy >= fEnemyFreq)
        {
            Vector2 enemyDirection = Vector2.Normalize(Player.playershape.Position - Startposition) * 100f;
            enemieslist.Add(new Enemy(Startposition, enemyDirection, Player.playershape.Position));
            fNextEnemy = 0;
        }

        for(int i = bulletslist.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {
            // Update Bullet
            Bullet bullets = bulletslist[i];   
            bullets.Update(gameTime, this.graphicsDevice, delta);       
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        Player.Draw(batch);
        foreach (Enemy enemies in enemieslist)
        {
            enemies.Draw(batch, myEnemy);
        } 
        foreach (Bullet bullets in bulletslist)
        {
            bullets.Draw(batch, myBullet);
        } 
    }
}
```

Enemy class:

```
public class Enemy
{
    private float nextShot = 0;
    private float shotFrequency = 1.0f;  
    Vector2 vPos;
    Vector2 vMove;
    Vector2 vPlayer;
    public Vector2 Bulletstartposition;
    public bool Remove;
    public bool Shot;

    public Enemy(Vector2 Pos, Vector2 Move, Vector2 Player)
    {
        this.vPos = Pos;
        this.vMove = Move;
        this.vPlayer = Player;
        this.Remove = false;
        this.Shot = false;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, GraphicsDeviceManager graphics, Vector2 PlayerPos, float delta)
    {           
        nextShot += delta;

        if (nextShot >= shotFrequency)
            {
            this.Shot = true;
            nextShot = 0;
            }

        if (!Remove)
        {
            float fMoveTime = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            this.vMove = Vector2.Normalize(PlayerPos - this.vPos) * 100f;
            this.vPos += this.vMove * fMoveTime;
            Bulletstartposition = this.vPos;

            if (this.vPos.X > graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth + 1)
            {
                this.Remove = true;
            }

            else if (this.vPos.X < -20)
            {
                this.Remove = true;
            }

            if (this.vPos.Y > graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight + 1)
            {
                this.Remove = true;
            }

            else if (this.vPos.Y < -20)
            {
                this.Remove = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D myTexture)
    {
        if (!Remove)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, this.vPos, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

Bullet class

```
public class Bullet
{
    Vector2 vPos;
    Vector2 vMove;
    Vector2 vPlayer;
    public bool Remove;

    public Bullet(Vector2 Pos, Vector2 Move, Vector2 Player)
    {
        this.Remove = false;
        this.vPos = Pos;
        this.vMove = Move;
        this.vPlayer = Player;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, GraphicsDeviceManager graphics, float delta)
    {
            if (!Remove)
            {
                float fMoveTime = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                this.vPos.X += this.vMove.X * fMoveTime;
                this.vPos.Y += this.vMove.Y * fMoveTime;

                if (this.vPos.X > graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth +1)
                {
                    this.Remove = true;
                }

                else if (this.vPos.X < -20)
                {
                    this.Remove = true;
                }

                if (this.vPos.Y > graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight +1)
                {
                    this.Remove = true;
                }

                else if (this.vPos.Y < -20)
                {
                    this.Remove = true;
                }
            }         
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D myTexture)
    {
        if (!Remove)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, this.vPos, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe don't post so much code but look at your code a little more and see what is the reason why it might be firing all the time.  Otherwise this is a decent question but not one that most people are going to learn from, very specific to your situation only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are never clearing the `Shot` flag. After you have an enemy shoot, just do `enemy.Shot = false;`.

Also, a tiny tip, when nextShot is >= shotFrequency, it's better to do this:

```
nextShot -= shotFrequency;
```

It accounts for the tiny bit of overlap when you go beyond shotFrequency.